# remove white space in front of comma or apostrophe - Python

Tags: python, string, removing-whitespace

How do I remove the white space in front of an apostrophe or comma so the sentence in print() will read better?

```
CTyear = 2020
Name1 = "Dave"
print("Hello",Name1,",","its the year",CTyear,".")
```

"Hello Dave , its the year 2020 ."<- how do I remove the white space in front of the apostrophe and comma? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
CTyear = 2020
Name1 = "Dave"
print(f"Hello {Name1}, it's the year {CTyear}.")
```

Output

```
Hello Dave, it's the year 2020.
```